# How do English speakers ask about something or someone's position in a series?

Tags: questions

For example the US presidents, how do you ask about Obama's or Washington's positions in the order of presidents without having to mention 1st or 44th.

Do you say:

Obama is what president of the US?

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> Where does Obama fall in the sequence of US presidents?

Comment: Also, where does he **come** in the sequence (etc). Common in British English especially when discussing sports results - Where did Jones come in the 500 metre race? Where did Manchester city come in the league table?